# White spaces added to XML file when setting a tags inner text to null? How to pass null to a XML file or remove a child node from XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, null

In my project i load an XML file and populate its tags by filling the inner text. I don't Populate all the nodes and leave some null.

After i save the XML file those child nodes inner text set to null are written as 5 white spaces??

How can i set the value of a node to be null?

Alternative how would i delete a child node out of my XML file?

Here is how i populate the inner text of the nodes, the best i can do is 1 white space, but i would like to have non.

---

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(MapPath(tempFolderPathAlt + "dvforms" + "\\XmlDataTemplate.xml"));

XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//FieldData");
foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
   {
      int Count = 0;
      foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) //For each child node in FieldData
        {
           if (PropInfo[Count].TagName == childNode.Name)
              {
                if (PropInfo[Count].TagValue != null)
                   {
                    node.SelectSingleNode(PropInfo[Count].TagName).InnerText = PropInfo[Count].TagValue;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     //node.RemoveChild(childNode);
                     //xmlDoc.
                     // xmlDoc.RemoveChild(childNode);
                     //node.RemoveChild(PropInfo[Count].TagName);
                     node.SelectSingleNode(PropInfo[Count].TagName).InnerText = " ";
                   }
                     PropInfo[Count].TagMod = childNode.Attributes.Item(0).InnerText;
                     PropInfo[Count].TagIncludeInPdf = childNode.Attributes.Item(1).InnerText;
               }
               Count = Count + 1;
         }
    }
```

Currently all the nulls i have set to one white space, i would like them as null or to delete them?

---

How my XML file looks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FormData Platform="Android" PlatformVersion="89" Version="360" DataVersion="1" Description="New Investec - Residential" FormId="9fe48133-ebec-415c-8581-22ba1bfcb237" FileId="d204b364-6b3f-46e0-beed-3f3b2783b8f3" EncryptionVerification="" CreatedBy="Johanc" EditedBy="Johanc" TrackingNum="FormMobi19e9ba3a-2c70-4a5a-a881-44cba4a031c5">
  <FieldData>
    <request_details_lightstone_report Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </request_details_lightstone_report>
    <request_details_export_template Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </request_details_export_template>
    <request_details_reason_for_valuatio Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </request_details_reason_for_valuatio>
    <request_details_valuation_job_numbe Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </request_details_valuation_job_numbe>

    <property_details_gps_location_lat Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">-29.965495</property_details_gps_location_lat>
    <property_details_gps_location_long Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">30.838881</property_details_gps_location_long>
    <property_details_address_address1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">8 LETHUBUHLE</property_details_address_address1>
    <property_details_address_address2 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">UMLAZI SOUTH</property_details_address_address2>
    <property_details_address_city Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">ETHEKWINI</property_details_address_city>
    <property_details_address_state Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">KWAZULU NATAL</property_details_address_state>
    <property_details_address_zip Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </property_details_address_zip>
    <property_details_locality_map Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">a8267608-6693-40d4-a3e6-d46dfd888037.jpg</property_details_locality_map>
    <property_details_type_of_ownership Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">Freehold</property_details_type_of_ownership>
    <property_details_text_box Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </property_details_text_box>
    <property_details_text_box_1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </property_details_text_box_1>
    <property_details_area_of_site Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">840</property_details_area_of_site>
    <field_group Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </field_group>
    <property_description_erf_number Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">532</property_description_erf_number>
    <property_description_portion_number Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">0</property_description_portion_number>
    <Property_description_township_name Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">UMLAZI DD</Property_description_township_name>
    <property_description_sectional_titl Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">
    </property_description_sectional_titl>
    <property_description_section_number Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"></property_description_section_number>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_box Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_box>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">, ETHEKWINI MUNICIPALITY</title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_1>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_2 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_2>
    <title_deed__municipal_information__2 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information__2>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_3 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes">
    </title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_3>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_area Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_area>
    <title_deed__municipal_information__1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information__1>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_area_1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_area_1>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_4 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_box_4>
    <title_deed__municipal_information_text_area_2 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </title_deed__municipal_information_text_area_2>
    <main_dwelling_text_box Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </main_dwelling_text_box>
    <main_dwelling_text_box_1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </main_dwelling_text_box_1>
    <main_dwelling_text_box_2 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </main_dwelling_text_box_2>
    <main_dwelling_text_box_3 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </main_dwelling_text_box_3>
    <valuation_certificate_signature_1 Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </valuation_certificate_signature_1>
    <valuation_certificate_professional_ Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"> </valuation_certificate_professional_>
  </FieldData>
  <Photos Mod="20010101010101" />
  <VoiceNotes />
  <Drawings Mod="20010101010101" />
  <FieldNotes />
</FormData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't write this line

```
node.SelectSingleNode(PropInfo[Count].TagName).InnerText = " ";
```

That will not set the value but node will be there.

or

```
node.SelectSingleNode(PropInfo[Count].TagName).InnerText = String.Empty;
```

That should work.

Milind

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the inner text to string.empty if the value is NULL. This is simply a guess

Comment: Thanks i have tried this with no success, both string.empty and "" create 5 white spaces inside my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

node.RemoveAll(); will get rid of the extra spaces if the only thing contained in "node" is the InnerText.